# Swift: creating initializer generates this error: " 'super' members cannot be referenced in a root class"

Tags: swift

I'm implementing a helper class for example:

```
class Helper {

    var myStr: String?

    init?(myStr:String) {
        super.init()
        self.myStr = myStr
    }
}
```

On this line `super.init()` I'm getting this error "'super' members cannot be referenced in a root class".

Any of you knows why I'm getting this error? or if there is a way for create the init without this error?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: What do you think `super.init()` does in your code? By the way, a helper class is usually a bad idea in a language like Swift. You have extensions, you don't need helpers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because this class has no superclass. It does not inherit from anything, and as such is a root class. A call to `super.init()` is for calling the initialiser of the superclass to ensure that inherited functionality is available as expected, but it has no relevance here.

---

Declaring a subclass that inherits from another class (a superclass) would look like this:

```
class Subclass: Superclass {
    // Code etc...
}
```